# Need a tag for vsts

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

Microsoft's Visual Studio Team Services currently has tag of vs-team-services. The norm is to call it VSTS. When I tried to create tag "vsts", validation error indicating that tag "vst" already exists. However, "vsts" is not the plural of "vst"; it is completely different.

Ideally, vsts would be the primary tag, and vs-team-services would be a synonym. However, the reverse of that would be fine if it is easier.

Comment: 3 and 4 letter acronyms for obscure topics are not popular.  They shouldn't be, too much collateral damage.

Comment: That makes sense. This question has already gotten 10 downvotes. It appears that [vst] is now gone, so it seems that the question did have value in that it helped to clean up tags. Still 10 downvotes. Seems that there's a flaw in the process. :-/

Comment: @HansPassant "3 or 4 letter acronyms for obscure topics are not popular". It is incredibly *common* to see 3 or 4 letter acronyms for topics that are obscure or otherwise. I'm not sure that *popularity* can be objectively measured given the fact that it would be inherently difficult to find all of the obscure topics. If you're saying that *the idea of having three or four letter acronyms for obscure topics as tags is not popular with the community*, that would be much easier to measure.

Comment: I understand the acronym dilemma. Was just frustrated with the downvotes. @aran-mulholland has great points in his answer regarding "vsts". FWIW, Visual Studio Team Services is becoming very popular. It would be helpful to fully address this, particularly with all of the tags that currently start with vsts.

Comment: I see now that "vs-team-services" tag has been renamed to "vsts". I've got a -8 on this entry. What changed?

Comment: Oh, I see now: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354655/284598

Answer (score 2):

The tag that can easily be used now is vs-team-services however having a vsts tag has merit as all of the related features for Visual Studio Team Services start with the vsts prefix

[image]

When entering a tag for a question this morning related to Visual Studio Team Services my first try was to enter vsts and as I saw all of the components of vsts I thought vsts was missing. When I tried to create the tag it wouldn't let me and as a result I came here to ask the question that the OP has asked. From reading his question I became aware of the vs-team-services tag, it isn't immediately obvious to a developer that uses VSTS and refers to it as VSTS all of the time for the tag to be missing. I think that it should be added especially if tags can be synonymous.

Comment: I agree. I went through exactly the same process. Consistency would be good, especially as VSTS grows in popularity.

Answer (score 1):

We need to be careful about using [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts) as a tag. These four letters were used for "Visual Studio Team System" (e.g. see [What are VSTS and TFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187345(v=vs.80).aspx)) for Visual Studio 2005). I have conversed with several people who have been using Visual Studio for over five years and they still refer to Visual Studio as VSTS.

I am not sure when Microsoft stopped using VSTS as a name for Visual Studio. Then recently, they renamed "Team Foundation Services" to be "Visual Studio Online" and then renamed it again to be "Visual Studio Team Services".

Comment: If you go up a couple of levels in the tree in the referenced link you'll see that VSTS and Visual Studio are (and were) different. This may help:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5(v=vs.80).aspx