# VSTS vs VS Team Services

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

So... Apparently Microsoft is taking a cue from the Colonel and rebranding Visual Studio Team Services (initials: VSTS) to the much shorter "VSTS", and has asked us to rename the [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services) tag to [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts).

[Last time we went around on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342786/need-a-tag-for-vsts), there was some concern that it would cause confusion with Microsoft's related Visual Studio Team Foundation product, which was *also* known as VSTS *back in the day*... But these days it appears to be more commonly referred to as Team Foundation Server, or simply [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs). Actually... That was the concern [the preceding time we discussed this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310569/rename-visual-studio-online-tag-to-vs-team-services-based-on-product-rename) as well, but the sole remaining trace of this seems to be [vsts2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts2010) as a synonym for [visual-studio-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010).

In the meantime, rather a lot of tags *prefixed with* `vsts-` have appeared:

- [vsts-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build)
- [vsts-build-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build-task)
- [vsts-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-api)
- [vsts-release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-release)
- [vsts-package-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-package-management)
- [vsts-local-build-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-local-build-agent)
- [vsts-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-extension)

All of them look to be used for questions about components of Team Services, Team Services itself, or occasionally Team Foundation Server because of course it still exists and who can honestly keep all this straight. Meanwhile, the one tag typing "vsts" *won't* find is [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services).

Aaanyway... As much of a headache as product branding is for tagging, it's hard to think of a reason why we shouldn't try to stick with the most current name for things when possible. So, anyone have any objections or concerns here?

Comment: Sounds good to me. I always use 'vsts' when googling.

Comment: I'm all for it. The old tag will be linked anyway I suppose... I spent some time about 6 months ago to clean up most of the vsts/vs*/tfs tags so it's already much better than before.

Comment: Just to throw in more confusion; how about the `ms-` and `microsoft-` prefixes; as is used for `ms-office`, `ms-security-essentials`, `ms-word`, 'microsoft-word', and 'microsoft-dynamics' tags?  I prefer it without those tags (less typing), but can see the argument that our current approach is inconsistent (or at least, this prefixing is currently only used where disambiguation is required; which requires you to be aware of the additional context of what terms could cause ambiguity in order to determine which convention would be used).

Comment: VSTS is now being rebranded to Azure DevOps.

Comment: Yep; renamed 'em all again, @KjellRilbe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373920/vsts-has-been-renamed-to-azure-devops-lets-talk-about-some-tags

Answer (score 14):

I don't see a problem with adding a tag synonym at this moment. "VSTS" is a rather random letter combination (I don't need to remind you how MS makes up acronyms for everything they can imagine) whose meaning isn't immediately apparent. So, until folks are familiar with the new abbreviation, [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services) is more descriptive.

Wikipedia uses a similar concept: when a term changes, they keep using the old one until the new one becomes prevalent in authoritative sources.

Comment: Given the quantity of prefixed tags (and activity in them), it kinda looks like we're already on that path - I think getting rid of the vsts synonyms for Visual Studio will help a bit with confusion, but probably not a lot.

Answer (score 11):

In contrast to ivan's answer I think the synonym should be the other way around, VSTS being the main tag. Like Stijn I too would Google as VSTS and before that VSO (Visual Studio Online) the old name.

This has been sat in my bookmarks for months already.

[image: VSTS]

Personally, VSTS as an acronym for Visual Studio Team Services makes sense to me. We don't have tags hypertext-markup-language or cascading-style-sheets.

Comment: On the other hand, CSS and Html is a well known abbreviation. VSTS is realy product specific. I am fine with both, but would prefer vs-team-services.

Comment: +1 to this. In my experience VSTS has become the dominant term; with VSO trailing slightly, then Visual Studio Team Services and Visual Studio Online terms taking the rear; i.e. with most people preferring less typing especially when dealing with such long names, and opting for the latest brand name.

Answer (score 4):

After reviewing the feedback here and getting a bit of clarification on why they're rebranding from Anisha Pindoria at MS, I went ahead and renamed the tag to [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts), with both [vs-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services) and [visual-studio-team-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-team-services) as synonyms. I also completely removed the old [vsts2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts2010) synonym of [visual-studio-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010).

Doing it this way *should* automatically remap everyone's tag favorites and subscriptions, while allowing folks who are interested in following the whole shebang to subscribe to (or simply search for) `vsts*` without getting superfluous results - and, of course, allow folks *asking* questions to choose the right tag regardless of what they start typing.

Of course, it's never quite that simple in practice... So don't hesitate to further improve on this scheme.

Comment: The branding logo is missing from the new vsts tag, caching?

Comment: Yup. Well, and I forgot to change the name there.

Answer (score 3):

I am happy with the name change, but I have a feeling that the `vsts-` prefix will be abused. The important thing to note is that VSTS is TFS in the cloud, so many of the questions about 'how do I accomplish x' will be applicable to both. Tagging with `vsts-` would unnecessarily restrict the scope of the question to one platform when it actually applies to both. Perhaps `vs-` could be used to mean `vsts-` and `tfs-`?

Comment: Agree with the overcreated tags. But `vs-` is not the same as `tfs-` or `vsts-`. Maybe it would be better to make all `vsts-` tags that are regarding a normal tfs feature, a synonyom of `tfs-`

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt `(vs)t(f)s-`?? Probably lead to even more confusion...

Comment: Near as I can tell, this is already happening and has been for some time (also some small overlap with things like git). Not sure there's any clever way around that, at least not from our end.

Comment: Is TFS not now 'VSTS on-premise' rather than having its own name?

Comment: TFS was around way before VSTS, so you can't say TFS is VSTS on premises. It is still well and truly supported, but updates to TFS happen on a preset release cycle whereas VSTS changes happen overnight (frustratingly out of the blue most of the time).